# How can I find the boot files for ubuntu in windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

New to the Linux community.
I recently installed Ubuntu with dual boot. I have used diskpart to assign the letter X for the system partition. When I go under X:/efi the Ubuntu folder cannot be found. I tried it with several laptops and I'm getting the same folder structure. This makes it very difficult for me to uninstall Linux. Actually, I'm dealing with an issue where boot entries reappear after deleting them from the BCD store upon reboot.

Comment: Each disk may have an EFI partition.  The Ubuntu installer will use the first EFI it finds, not the one you might have specified for the install.  Do you have two disks, and did you try to install Ubuntu on the second one?  Look in the other disk's EFI partition for EFI/ubuntu...

Comment: Yes, that was indeed the case. I found the EFI folder for ubuntu on another hard drive. But I have also seen Windows and Ubuntu on the same EFI folder, when does that happen?

Answer (score 1):

Each disk may have an EFI partition. The Ubuntu installer will use the first EFI it finds, not the one you might have specified for the install. If you have two disks and tried to install Ubuntu on the second one, look in the other disk's EFI partition for EFI/ubuntu...

Be aware of the launchpad bug 1396379 - Installer uses first EFI
system partition found even when directed otherwise (and the
workarounds in the comments):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379

Add yourself to the bug's "Does this affect me?" list (in the upper
left corner). If list count gets big enough, maybe the bug will be fixed.

The "Wrong ESP" bug puts the grub boot onto your Windows disk, even if you
specify the location of the bootloaders as your second disk. However, some
grub files are in the Ubuntu root on the other disk, so the system wont boot
without the second disk. This is why the recommendation to remove the Windows
disk is made -- any other way to disable the disk will also be OK, but removal
is certain.

Installing Ubuntu to a second disk is more difficult than it should be.

Comment: It might be a good idea for you to upvote the main question to prevent it from being jerk reviewed: https://askubuntu.com/review/close/1267030.